# IICS Mapping task

Tags: iics

"We have a mapping that is simple; it is only responsible for performing an insert or update as needed. If it is a new record, it inserts it, but if it is an old record, it updates it. We want to create two mapping tasks using the same mapping: one for daily loading and another for weekly extraction. The problem we have is that in the case of a weekly load, we need to truncate the target and only perform inserts. However, in the case of a daily load, we should perform both inserts and updates."

"We expect that when we run the weekly process, the target will be truncated and fully reloaded. However, in the case of the daily process, it should only perform insertions or updates."